# How to hide articles from Blog Category mode

Tags: module, category-blog

I'm trying to make a more dynamic News & Events posting process on a website.

To do this I'm using the free version of Deluxe News by JoomlaXTC.

---

### Overview

[This is the result](http://www.liceocannizzaro.it/) I'd like to achieve, but split in 2 columns rather than in just one.

I have already modified the template so I now have two new positions called csx and cdx in order to put in there my new News & Events modules.

---

### Problem

That website uses on its Homepage a Blog Category mode, loading a category we'll call "X". On the JoomlaXTC module, which is in the same Homepage, it loads the very same category "X".

What this should do, is showing a new article with the module setup whenever a new article is added in that category "X".

But instead, when I do this on my website, it doesn't just show the Module, but the articles in the category as well (as it should indeed do that Blog Category mode). You can take a look at my [testing page](http://www.liceocroceroma.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=18&Itemid=381). (Yes, it's the live website, but I'm just editing a sub-menu I added just to test this, I had no time to make a localhost for this).

---

### Question

How did that other website managed to remove the "show" method of the Blog Category mode? On that website it just shows the JoomlaXTC module, I don't know how though. Settings of the module on both websites are the same.

Comment: Check your template framework if there is a feature that can hide/override component on Frontpage or specific menu.